# Bottlepy return an numpy image after resize an image

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, bottle

I'm trying to create a service in python, with bottlepy.
This service should read an image from a URL and must return the same image with a new size.

But I have two problems:

1 - I can not read the URL

2 - I can not return an image numpy without writing to disk

```
@route('/resize_image/<x>/<y>/<url>', method='GET')
def resize(x=100, y=100, url='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/53/Wikipedia-logo-en-big.png'):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
    if cap.isOpened():
        ret, image = cap.read()
    else:
        raise HTTPError(400, "ERROR")

    resized = cv2.resize(image, (x, y), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

    response.set_header('Content-type', 'image/jpeg')
    return resized.bytes()
```

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pilbox

Comment: Thanks, but I need do this inside my service, I need other solution.

Comment: What does "can not" mean? What output do you expect, and what output are you seeing?